# Show $ x^4 + y^4 - 4(x - y)^2 \geq \alpha (x^2 + y^2) + \beta $?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, nonlinear-optimization

**The problem**

Let $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $f(x,y) = x^4 + y^4 - 4(x - y)^2$. Show
$$ \exists \alpha \in ] 0 , + \infty [ \mbox{, } \exists \beta \in \mathbb{R} \mbox{ s.t } f(x,y) \geq \alpha(x^2 + y^2) + \beta  $$

**My questions and my works**

I have to prove that the inequality is true, but I don't think it is true. When I've represented the inequality on GeoGebra I get this

[image]

where the blue is $f(x,y)$ and the purple is $\alpha(x^2 + y^2) + \beta$ with $\alpha = 1,\beta = 0$.

But, in my works, when I developed $f(x,y)$ I found

$$ f(x,y) \leq x^4 + y^4 $$

and this formula seems to be correct because I got the following representation

[image]

where the blue is $f(x,y)$ and the purple is $x^4 + y^4$.

Actually, I am not sure the inequality on the problem is true. I think we should show

$$ f(x,y) \leq \alpha(x^4 + y^4) + \beta $$

for some $\alpha,\beta$.

is my intuition correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\alpha=2$ and $\beta=-50$.

We need to prove that:
$$x^4+y^4-4(x-y)^2\geq2(x^2+y^2)-50$$ or
$$x^4+y^4+4(x+y)^2\geq10(x^2+y^2)-50$$ or
$$(x^2-5)^2+(y^2-5)^2+4(x+y)^2\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

What you showed is
$$f(x,y) \le \alpha (x^4+y^4) + \beta $$
where $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta = 0$. Although this is correct, it's not what the exercize is asking you to show.

Here is an idea: if you take any $\alpha > 0$, say for example $\alpha = 1$, then you can show that
$$g(x,y)=f(x,y)- \alpha (x^2+y^2)$$
has an absolute minimum. That's because for $x,y \to \infty$ the function blows up to $+ \infty$.
Hence you can define $$\beta = \min_{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2} g(x,y)$$ and you are done.